# I have doubts with regards to Nodejs installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

I have currently installed the latest version of node that is 20.10.0 in order to start using React.
What can I do with the old version? Can I delete it or should I keep it?
If I delete it, will it cause any problem to the existing files that used node?

Answer (score 1):

there might be some package breakage issues,using NVM(node version manager) to switch between node version would be great for managing the project.